# HAR File Structure for YSLOW command line report

Tags: file, yslow, har

I am running YSlow against .HAR files generated through fiddler to get a report on the page speed and other yslow rules of a site. However the report generated through YSlow command line versus the report generated by the chrome YSLOW add on are completely different (the YSlow add on actually generates a meaningful report and the command line report is empty). YSlow command line does not seem to recognize the entries in my .HAR files so there are no "offenders". 
Can't find an example of how .HAR files should be structured for YSlow command line to recognize the entries- is it possible the YSlow command line needs .HAR files to be modified in order to generate a meaningful report and if so what are the necessary modifications?

Answer (score -1):

No, YSlow command line does not require any HAR modification. Any well defined HAR file, including the one generated by Fiddler, should be ok.
Regarding YSlow addon vs command line differences, check it out [YSlow ruleset limitation](http://yslow.org/ruleset-limitations/) page from [yslow.org](http://yslow.org).

You might also try generating HAR file from webpagetest.org which provides a HAR output link, e.g.: http://www.webpagetest.org/export.php?test=131031_KA_J99

As you can see, YSlow command line (via [nodejs server](http://yslow.org/node-server/)) reports properly from the HAR file above: http://yslow.aws.af.cm/?har=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webpagetest.org%2Fexport.php%3Ftest%3D131031_KA_J99&i=grade